os.setuid errors with [Errno 22] Invalid argument
I am trying to use os.setuid in an unshared user namespace, but it returns an error, which I cannot seem to find happening to anyone anywhere.
Code (this is a MRE, not part of my program):
import os
os.unshare(os.CLONE_NEWUSER) # this unshares the user namespace, which should allow me to setuid (it is fake-ish)
os.setuid(0) # err
os.setgid(0) # err
os.system('/bin/bash') # launch bash

Error:
$ python mre.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/mre/mre.py", line 3, in <module>
    os.setuid(0)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

I am using Python 3.12.4, on Manjaro Linux. It doesn't work when ran as root or a normal user. Python isn't setuid, and I can unshare the user namespace (as it doesn't fail, setuid does, and I'm pretty sure that unshare doesn't fail silently.). It only errors if I unshare the user namespace.
Can anyone help me out here?

How are you executing this code?  Does it have permission to assume the root UID?

on what system do you run it? with what Python version? I run on Linux Mint with Python 3.10 and it says that os doesn't have unshare and it doesn't have CLONE_NEWUSER

Python would have to be setuid to root for you to be able to use os.setuid(0)

@furas: os.unshare was added in 3.12.

@Barmar: They’re asking about using user namespaces.

You need to set up UID/GID maps, I believe.
